# missing openssl extension phpmailer

Tags: php, email, openssl, smtp, phpmailer

I am try to use PHPMailer to sending email in company virtual host, but come with error openssl missing.
I tried my method is work on local but is not working when i am using company virtual host.

I had checked:

1. openssl is enabled on `php.ini` and `phpinfo` also stated enabled.
2. `extension_dir` is also enabled

but i feeling weird is the `opensssl_conf` under the apache environment is not showing, i used `setenv` also cannot work with.

Is it i also need to setup environment variable? But my local machine is not set with environment variable.

***UPDATE***

Thanks for @ Synchro pointing out the `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` , seem like PHP5.3.10 is not supported `defined('OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256');`

So current situation was

`SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)`

checked the [PHPMAILER Troubleshooting](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) section connect fail(), not sure which causes this error, the firewall is off and I am no idea on the firewall blocking outbound SMTP.

ADDITION: using `telnet host port` is stated connection fail, is it the causes?

Comment: apt-get install openssl

Comment: @MaxMuster: only when OP use Ubuntu/Debian system

Comment: @catcon are there also other out there ?

Comment: It sounds like your company virtual host is misconfigured, but there's not enough info to go on here. PHPMailer checks whether the constant called `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` is defined in order to determine whether the openssl extension is available.

Comment: @Synchro seem like there is not openssl because it throw the exception but i checked the phpinfo openssl is enabled

Comment: It may be that you have more than one PHP instance?

Comment: @Synchro  I checked the php.ini path is corrected, but your point may be true, has any way to checked the openssl is installed?

Comment: OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256 is available for php 5.3.10?

Comment: now has no error on missing extension but is SMTP error: connect fail

Comment: So now is the time to read [the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and use the tests it describes to diagnose your problem – post the results in your question, not a comment. It's most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP.